# Grouping with SQL using Max, Min, Avg and dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: My Table]

I have a table as shown above, every 10 minutes a record for each ChannelID is put in the table.

I want to get the max, min and avg for each day for each channel, is this possible?

I am using MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: u want answer using query?

Comment: Have you attempted anything?  Your title suggests that you know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you know what to do, so I'm guessing the only thing you are missing is that you need to trunc your time value from your date, so each day will be recognized as a group. You can do it by using `CAST AS DATE`

```
SELECT cast([dateTime] as date) as Your_Date,ChannelID,
       max(reading) as max_reading,
       min(reading) as min_reading,
       avg(reading) as avg_reading
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY cast([dateTime] as date) ,ChannelID
```

Comment: Fantastic thanks so much, I've spend ages making it way too complicated - perfect answer

Comment: Is there any way to return the date as a date 'Your_Date'? At the moment it's returning a string, TIA

Comment: Its a date not a string.. @juliafield